# Apache2 will not start on OpenSUSE after enabling mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache-2.2, opensuse, sles, mod-pagespeed

I have a linode VPS, running openSUSE 12.1 (A little outdated, but stable). I have installed the RPMS for mod_pagespeed.
mod_pagespeed.conf has "ModPagespeed on".

Restarting apache fails after enabling pagespeed. the errors are not very helpful.

```
li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 # a2enmod pagespeed
li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 # service apache2 restart

redirecting to systemctl
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 # systemctl status apache2.service
apache2.service - apache
          Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled)
          Active: failed since Thu, 06 Jun 2013 20:49:00 +0000; 1s ago
         Process: 6701 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd2 -D SYSTEMD -k stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 6704 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/start_apache2 -D SYSTEMD -k start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        Main PID: 6637 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/apache2.service

li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 # a2dismod pagespeed
li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 # service apache2 restart
redirecting to systemctl
li361-39:/usr/lib64/apache2 #
```

And the error log (/var/log/apache2/error_log) is useless as well.

```
[Thu Jun 06 20:48:59 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jun 06 20:49:12 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Jun 06 20:49:13 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0k PHP/5.4.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

EDIT This is from /var/log/messages

`Jun 12 14:24:14 li361-39 start_apache2[27951]: httpd2-prefork: Syntax error on line 116 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_pagespeed.so into server: /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_pagespeed.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_config`

Full Log is here: http://pastebin.com/hjnbZZTr

I've tried looking for other logs and checking the mod_pagespeed.conf against posts claiming it works and nothing is striking as wrong. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try looking at /var/log/messages?

Comment: Thanks that has a lot more info i didnt have before, edited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you mentioned has to do with the API compatibility between pagespeed and apache. Some versions of apache cannot use pagespeed (or so it was when I tackled this problem) ... 
What is the actual version of apache you are using and that of pagespeed.

Also, did you install apache and pagespeed using YAST (or what ever it was opensuse uses :D) ?

Comment: Yep, installed via YAST.  Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE)

Comment: even pagespeed ?

Comment: Yep, added the repo here, installed via yast. The provider says he also uses 12.1 (same as me) https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq#suse

Comment: Strange things have happened. I have a client that's running pagespeed on that version, although I thing it's better if you ran it from a 2.4 latest version, if possible. Also, run `ldd /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_pagespeed.so`. A library is clearly missing, but since you installed via YAST all should be in place ... post back the result, please.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into upgrading to 2.4 and see if that gets me anywhere.